# Make inner div resize to fit its container given dynamic height footer below it

Tags: html, css

I have two divs stacked vertically in a container div. The container div has `height: 100%`, and the bottom inner-div has dynamic height. I want the top div to take up the remaining space of the container, such that the bottom div is effectively fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

```
<div class="container" style="height: 100%">
  <div class="my-height-should-be-the-remainder-of-the-container" style="overflow: scroll">
    <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
  </div>

  <div class="my-height-should-take-priority-over-the-top-div">
    <p>My height should dynamically change depending on my content</p>
    <p>As a result, my content should never overflow</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `display: table` with the inner divs as `display: table-row`, but can't get the top div to respect the `overflow: scroll`; it just pushes the bottom div outside of the viewport.

I know I could use `position: fixed` on the bottom div, then use javascript to dynamically alter the `padding-bottom` of the top div, but would love to find a CSS-only solution, preferably one without flexbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an absolutely positioned div around the content you want to scroll, it will appear to the layout to take up no space, so the other content will win out in a table based layout.  You can then use overflow:auto on a wrapper of the absolutely positioned div if there is need of it.

Example :

```css
body, html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  display:table;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tr{
  display:table-row;
}
.td{
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
}
.header{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;

}
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  min-height:45px;
}
.content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.footer{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tr header">
    <div class='td'>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
          <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
          <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
          <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
          <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr footer">
    <p>My height should dynamically change depending on my content</p>
    <p>As a result, my content should never overflow</p>
    <p>My height should dynamically change depending on my content</p>
    <p>As a result, my content should never overflow</p>
    <p>My height should dynamically change depending on my content</p>
    <p>As a result, my content should never overflow</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/j7m3yLp7/1/

**More details** : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2015/02/20/filling-the-remaining-height-of-a-container-while-handling-overflow-in-css-ie8-firefox-chrome-safari/

Answer (score 1):

You said preferably not flexbox based, but here is what that would be like if you were to lift that restriction:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}
#top {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    This is the top.
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    This is the bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really excited for flexbox to be both widely supported AND consistent, then we can finally do away with a lot of the insanities of modern CSS tricks. Support has come a long way, but behavior across browsers still too inconsistent for my liking.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is what u need.
the top div will be 200px high at max.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.top {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: green;
    height: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="height: 100%;background-color: yellow;">
  <div class="top" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <p>My content should scroll if I become too small to show all of it</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <p>My height should dynamically change depending on my content</p>
    <p>As a result, my content should never overflow</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the height of the bottom div is dynamic depending on the content

Comment: yeap. it will be adjusted when the content changes.